# Showing Nested objects in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a nested object in document. In kibana 3, I am not able to add a panel for any of these nested object. E.g.

```
            {
                "location": [
                    0.023027
                    ,
                    51.58011
                ],
                "itemList": [
                    {
                        "make": "x",
                        "model": "y"
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "make": "a",
                        "model": "b"
                    }
                ],
                "somekey": "1234",
                "dateTime": "01/10/2005 22:43"
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
```

And my mapping looks like:

```
{
"order": 0,
"template": "*",
"settings": {},
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "string_not_analyzed": {
                    "mapping": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "match": "*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp_hours_minutes": {
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"
                    },
                    "match": "dateTime"
                }
            },
            {
                "geo_location_data":{
                    "mapping":{
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "match": "location"
                }
            },
            {
                "my_nested_mapping":{
                    "mapping":{
                        "type": "nested",
                        "include_in_parent": true,
                        "store": "yes"
                    },
                    "match": "*List"
                }
            }
        ],
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true,
            "store": true,
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZ"
        },
        "date_detection": "false",
        "_all": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
}
```

On kibana 3 when adding a term chart, I can select in dropdown 'itemList.make', however in the pie chart they come all as empty. Can someone throw some light on this please. Is this even possible.

On inspection kibana runs following query that returns zero results when run independently from head plugin.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/data/_search?pretty' -d '{
"facets": {
"terms": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "itemList.make",
    "size": 10,
    "order": "count",
    "exclude": []
  },
  "facet_filter": {
    "fquery": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match_all": {}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"size": 0
}'
```

In Elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) nested queries have path defined which i don't see being added by kibana.

Is there a way to get nested objects displayed in a kibana 3 panel?

Comment: It should work. Can you show the full object? Have you tried setting include_in_root to true?